# How to get x and y position of user click in Eclipse plugin + RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, jface, rcp

I am developing a plugin for email client using JFace + RCP using Eclipse. I am not developing any screens using eclipse, mail client will be the screen for this plugin.

I want to get the user clicked position in client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `addFilter` method of `Display` to add a listener that is called for all mouse down events in the SWT code:

```
Display display = Display.getDefault();

display.addFilter(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener()
  {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event)
     {
       System.out.println("event " + event);

       if (event.widget instanceof Control) {
         Control control = (Control)event.widget;
         System.out.println("display " + control.toDisplay(event.x, event.y));
       }
     }
 });
```

The `Event` passed to `handleEvent` has `x` and `y` fields for the mouse down event - these are relative to the control containing the event. The control is given in the `widget` field. I have shown code to convert these values to be absolute display values.

Note: This only works for mouse down events in the current application and only for SWT code. In the past Lotus Notes used a lot of native code where this would not work, I don't know if this is still the case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried in `ActionSetHandler` class which implements `IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate` but getting some errors. I updated my question pls take a look.

Comment: Your `Event` import is wrong. It must be `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event`

Comment: Thanks greg, its fine. Is there a possible to get the tooltip of the clicked image? I have included the screen in my question.  Because, It differs based on the monitors sizes.

Comment: No idea. It depends on what control is displaying the tool tip and how it is doing it. In any case that is a separate question. Accept this answer and ask a new question with as much detail as possible (such as the details in the event).